# How to make cmd window a quarter of my screen

Tags: cmd

How do I make my cmd window a quarter of my screen using the mode command? I know that using mode 1000 will make it fullscreen, but I don't know how to make it a quarter of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you are entering in mode 1000 you are just telling the computer you want 1000 columns to display in command prompt. Full screen on my monitor is mode 319. Anything more causes a scroll bar to appear on the bottom.

I would recommend figuring out your max columns, then divide the result by 4. That should give you a command window that takes up 1/4th of the screen starting at the edge of the monitor.